Task.Run only runs synchronously?
I'm trying to write a method that reads each page of a pdf, but since it takes a significant amount of time to read each page through the api and I'm looking at pdfs hundreds of pages long, I want to queue the reading of each page asynchronously and then return the results when they're ready, so multiple pages are being read at once.
I use Task.Run to "queue" the task, and I expect to see the Debug log print the pages out of order, but they only execute in order, so I think they are being run synchronously. Any ideas?
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (Page page in _pdfDoc.GetPages()) {
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
        //tried adding await Task.Yield() here, doesn't work
        Debug.WriteLine("searching page " + page.Number);
        if (page.Text.Contains(query)) {
            pagesWithQuery.Add(page.Number);
        }
        howManySearched += 1;
        Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => {
            searchProgress.Value = howManySearched;
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
    // await task; <== does nothing??
}
// await Task.WhenAll(tasks); <== also nothing


You'd need an await Task.WhenAll(tasks) on the outside of the loop, not the inside.

see edit, adding the line doesn't have an effect

Just to confirm Task.WhenAll(tasks); uncommented, but the await in the loop remains commented doesn't work?

Kevin: no it does not. KJ: I know that the behavior of the pdf library is synchronous, so I don’t know if the pdf specific stuff is relevant , for the sake of the question one can assume it could be replaced with a synchronous call to anything; I’m also doing a rewrite of a web app I previously wrote and that was how I implemented it before

Have you done any profiling? The .Contains is likely really fast, so the performance issue is probably in the library pdf parsing code. But is that in GetPages() or in page.Text? If it is the former you will probably not gain much, and just made your code more complicated and error prone.

@gumydev1 Task.Run doesn't run synchronously. That's a fact, like the sun rising from the east. It's not up to debate. The question's code though is too convoluted and suffers from race conditions (howManySearched) , captured lambda variables (searchProgress.Value = howManySearched;), out of sequence updates, .UIThread.InvokeAsync and flooding the CPU with more threads than there are cores to process them. You can eliminate most of this code by using await Parallel.ForEachAsync(pages,(page,cancellationToken)=>....

Reporting progress should be done using Progress. The progress Action is the one that should increment counters and print progress. If you want to keep track of pages you can add them to a ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentDictionary. If you want the pages to be processed in some way by another task or the UI thread, you can use a Channel. You can use a Channel as an ordered and buffered alternative to Progress<> too

Hi, thanks for your answer; just to clarify, I'm using Avalonia library for progress and it has a ProgressBar element which I assumed doesn't have another way to update, the progress bar currently works as expected, but should I still be using Progress class?

@gumydev1 using the Progress<T> makes your code prettier, and more meaningful. The performance is the same with the Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync. If you report too frequently, they both have the same bad behavior (the UI freezes), because the UI message loop is flooded with messages.


I use Task.Run to "queue" the task, and I expect to see the Debug log print the pages out of order, but they only execute in order, so I think they are being run synchronously.

You don't have enough data to support this assumption. You are only logging the starting of each Task:
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("searching page " + page.Number);

...but you have no idea when the Task completes. You could get a better idea about the level of concurrency achieved by your code, by doing something like this:
object locker = new();
int concurrencyCounter = 0;
int maxConcurrency = 0;

Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int concurrency = Interlocked.Increment(ref concurrencyCounter);
    lock (locker) maxConcurrency = Math.Max(maxConcurrency, concurrency);
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("searching page " + page.Number);

        // Do work with the PDF page...

    } finally { Interlocked.Decrement(ref concurrencyCounter); }
});

//...

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Debug.WriteLine($"Maximum concurrency: {maxConcurrency}");

As a side note, there is a ton of idiomaticity in your code. You are not taking advantage of either the Parallel class or the AsParallel PLINQ operator, nor the Progress<T> class, and I suspect that there are also race conditions around the use of the undefined variables howManySearched and pagesWithQuery.

un-idiomaticity surely?

@Charlieface I mean that they are doing things their own way, instead of using established tools and patterns.

@Theodor Zoulias hey thanks for this, however I tried this and the max concurrency turns out to be 1 as I suspected. I also tried using Parallel.ForEachAsync, giving the same result. I don't know if this would be an issue but this code is being run inside its own asynchronous Task.Run so that it won't clog the UI (the UI works and is smooth). is there anything that would cause each Task.Run in the loop to be waiting for the previous one to finish? I've never programmed in C# before so I don't know the conventions

@gumydev1 that's unexpected. The only thing that could cause the max concurrency to stay at 1, is a heavily saturated ThreadPool. Not only the ThreadPool must be out of available workers, but there should be some other concurrent operation that is stealing the new threads that the ThreadPool injects when it is saturated (it's one new thread per second). You could try increasing preemptively the number of threads that the ThreadPool creates immediately on demand, for example with ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);, and see if it makes any difference.

@gumydev1 there is also the possibility that the work inside the Task.Run is so minuscule, that the action completes almost instantly. You could try adding a Thread.Sleep(100); somewhere inside the action, and see if it makes any difference in the maximum concurrency.

@gumydev1 you could also try running your application without the debugger attached. Sometimes the debugger interferes in undesirable ways, and you end up debugging the debugger instead of debugging your application.

@TheodorZoulias found the issue. the library i'm using (pdfpig) has a lock on access to the file, which blocks the other threads from reading it until the current thread is finished. so not my code issue. thanks for the help though

@gumydev1 yeah, something like that was possible. But it still doesn't explain why there is no concurrency inside the Task.Run.

There's no doubt about Task.Run. There are a lot of problems in this code though that give the wrong impression, some caused by the unnecessary complexity:

Race conditions in howManySearched mean it's incorrectly incremented
Lambda variable capture in () => {searchProgress.Value = howManySearched;} which means the active variable value at the time of execution is shown, not the value when InvokeAsync was called.
Possibly flooding the CPU with more threads than cores. Threads can't run if there's no free core to run them.
Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync doesn't guarantee processing order. And the UI thread itself requires a core to run, just like other threads.

All of these can give the impression that howManySearched jumps from 0 to maximum, simply because that's the value when the UI finally gets around to displaying it.
.NET offers many ways to process data concurrently in a far easier way.

To process multiple items concurrently in a controlled manner, use Parallel.ForEachAsync.
To report progress use Progress.
If you want to store the found pages you can use a concurrent collection like ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentDictionary<T>.
If you want to process the found pages in sequence in another thread or the UI thread itself, you can use a Channel<T>.

The question's code can be replaced with :
record SearchProgress(int Number,bool Finished);
int _searched;
ConcurrentDictionary<int,Page> _foundPages=new ConcurrentDictionary<int,Page>();
...

async Task FindInDocument(string query)
{
    var pages=_pdfDoc.GetPages();
    //Set up the UI
    ResetSearchProgress(pages.Count);

    var progress=new Progress<string>(ReportProgress);

    //Perform the search
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(pages,(page,ct)=>
    {
        progress.Report(new SearchProgress(page.Number,false);
        if (page.Text.Contains(query)) 
        {      
            // Assume there are no duplicate page numbers 
            _foundPages.TryAdd(page.Number,page);
        }
        progress.Report(new SearchProgress(page.Number,true);
    });

    //We're back on the UI thread
    FinishSearchProgress();
}

The methods that reset the counts, progress bar and dictionary were extracted in separate methods to clean things up a bit and remove any dependencies on UI elements from the search code
void ResetSearchProgress(int pageCount)
{
    _searched=0;
    _foundPages.Clear();

    searchProgress.Value=0;
    searchProgress.Maximun=pageCount;
}

void FinishSearchProgress()
{
    searchProgress.Value=0;
    txtStatus.Text=$"Found {_foundPages.Count} pages";
}

The ReportProgress method updates the found count and displays a status text. Assuming searchProgress is a searchProgress, searchProgress.Increment() is used instead of setting the value directly. _searched isn't really needed, at least not for the progress bar.
void ReportProgress(SearchProgress p)
{
    _searched++;

    searchProgress.Increment(1);
    txtStatus.Text=p.Finished?$"Searched Page {p.Number}"
                             :$"Searching Page {p.Number}";
    
}

The SearchProgress type can be as complex as needed,eg including a full message, timings, an Enum for the status instead of bool Finished etc.

"Possibly flooding the CPU with more threads than cores." -- This is true, but shouldn't be a big deal. All popular operating systems are known to handle well this situation, by assigning CPU time-slices to each thread, fairly and efficiently. I am not saying that it's ideal. Only just that it's not big deal.

Using 70 instead of 30 servers for the same load is a big deal. Or using a bigger cloud VM instead of the one you really wanted. A Thinkpad crashing due to overheating because cores were at 100% for too long is also a big deal (that was Python multiprocessing though). We obviously have very different loads in mind.

Never mind what happens when IIS starts recycling web servers due to high CPU usage during peak hours. That's a great way to crash all 70 servers
